# Как задать описание параметра slash-команды disnake.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Возможно ли как-то задать описание аргументов в slash-команде `disnake.py`?

[image: вместо "-" описание]

Чтобы в команде вместо `-` было описание

P.S **Пример:**

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def play(ctx: disnake.CommandInteraction, url): #описание для url
```

Comment: Было бы славно, если прикрепили [минимальный код](/help/mcve), что бы можно было ответ сделать более подробным!

Comment: @mironovmeow мне две строчки демонстрировать?)

Comment: Да, почему бы и нет?

Comment: @mironovmeow готово

Comment: QuL1ux, я тоже обновил свой ответ, теперь, думаю, понятнее стало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже узнал решение

Достаточно указать после нужного параметра:

```
commands.Param(description='Описание')
```

**Итог:**

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def play(ctx: disnake.CommandInteraction, url: str = commands.Param(description='Описание')):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не работал с [disnake.py](https://disnake.dev/), но, посмотрев в документации, я нашёл, что [`@bot.slash_command()`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#disnake.ext.commands.Bot.slash_command) принимает поле `description`.

> **description (Optional[Union[str, Localized]]) –**
> The description of the slash command. It will be visible in Discord.

Скорее всего это именно то, что вам нужно:

```py
@bot.slash_command(description="Полезное описание /play")
async def play(ctx: disnake.CommandInteraction, url): #описание для url
    ...
```

Comment: Это описание команды, а не параметра. Я уже нашел решение

Comment: Тогда, может, оставите решение, что бы другие тоже узнали?

Comment: Да конечно, сейчас...